# Presenting long data in table on web

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm using D3 and Crossfilter to visualize data on my web page.
These two great tools do an amazing job but at the end, data need to be presented to the user in a table.

The table is built from many rows, each has 5 columns.
One column is really long, can be 1000 chars long.
I was wondering what's the best way to represent such data in a table, without ruining the UI and user experience.

Currently, it looks much like the Crossfilter example that can be found here:
http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

Just imagine that the middle column in the table, is long as I mentioned.

I hope you got my question right, I do thank you for your time and help.

Comment: How important is the data in that column?  could it be shortened/truncated? you could also share a screenshot of the table in question

Comment: the data has to be untouched. I can't share a picture of the table but if it's really needed, just look at the table in the website I've mentioned in the question and imagine that one of the columns is really really long.

Comment: why not shorten it like if its above 10 chars substring and append with ...
some thing like "very very verylong text" becomes "very ver..."

Comment: how would the user see the data inside that way? or copy it if needed?